# I cant select html elements with the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to select a collection of elements, but it doesnt seem to work.
I think I know where the error is coming from but have no clue of how to solve it.

EDIT:
I think its not working because the BorderItem element is run before the DOM renders the HTML in getItemBorders()

Here is the code:

```
function getItemBorders(item){
    let carrier=``;
        for(let i=0; i<itemsArray.length; i++){
            for(let j=0; j<item.length; j++){
            if(itemsArray[i].alpha3Code==item[j]){
            carrier+=`<div class="border-item"><button class="">${itemsArray[i].name}</button></div>`
        }}}
        borderClicked();
    return carrier;
}
function borderClicked(){
    const BorderItem=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.border-item button'));
    for(let i=0; i<BorderItem.length; i++){
       console.log(BorderItem[i].innerHTML);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the borderClicked is called before returning the variable 'carrier' from getItemBorders which i called it in a variable and then assigned it to the html.